# SAP Hybris - Tomcat ignoring memory settings

Tags: java, tomcat, jvm, sap-commerce-cloud

I'm running a local installation of SAP Hybris 1811. I'm trying to increase its memory size since I've been getting OutOfMemory exceptions during SOLR index jobs.

However, I'm not able to reliably increase the memory via any method I've tried. Sometimes after struggling a lot (building the app multiple times, restarting, etc.) Hybris is able to see and use the set memory (I check this using backoffice), but most of the time it defaults to 2 GB and runs out of memory quickly.

What I've tried:

- `set JAVA_OPTS=-Xms10G -Xmx10G;` in `catalina.bat`
- `tomcat.javaoptions=-Xmx10G -Xms10G` in `local.properties`

What is the correct way to reliably set a higher memory for local Hybris server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a bit of digging, I found that the memory limit was ignored only when I've tried to run Hybris server with the `debug` parameter. I discovered that the properties I've tried to set using `tomcat.javaoptions` were not in the `wrapper-debug.conf` file which is used when starting the server in debug mode.

Long story short:

`tomcat.javaoptions` only gets applied to the default `wrapper.conf` file and is ignored when launching the server with any parameter such as *debug*.

For the changes to be applied to the `wrapper-debug.conf`, I needed to use **`tomcat.debugjavaoptions`** property.

In the end, my config file with working memory limit looks like this:

```
...
tomcat.javaoptions=-Xmx10G -Xms5G
tomcat.debugjavaoptions=-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=8000,suspend=n -Xmx10G -Xms5G
```

Answer (score 13):

Please try the following in your local.properties:

```
tomcat.generaloptions=-Xmx10G -ea -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dorg.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperManager.mbean=true -Djava.endorsed.dirs="%CATALINA_HOME%/lib/endorsed" -Dcatalina.base=%CATALINA_BASE% -Dcatalina.home=%CATALINA_HOME% -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8  -Djava.util.logging.config.file=jdk_logging.properties -Djava.io.tmpdir="${HYBRIS_TEMP_DIR}"
```

Please make sure to execute `ant` after making this change. As a general note, whenever you make any change related to tomcat, you need to execute `ant`.

For production environment, you can set this property as follows:

```
java.mem=10G
tomcat.generaloptions=-Xmx${java.mem} -Xms${java.mem} -Xss256K -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled -XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled -XX:+CMSScavengeBeforeRemark  -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails -Xloggc:"${HYBRIS_LOG_DIR}/tomcat/java_gc.log" -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dorg.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperManager.mbean=true -Djava.endorsed.dirs=../lib/endorsed -Dcatalina.base=%CATALINA_BASE% -Dcatalina.home=%CATALINA_HOME% -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djava.util.logging.config.file=jdk_logging.properties -Djava.io.tmpdir="${HYBRIS_TEMP_DIR}" -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000
```

Comment: `ant server` is a minimal command which will update the server w/ revised `local.properties` config, without running through all the tasks via just `ant`.

Comment: @quickshiftin I've always used `ant deploy` to quickly apply tomcat configuration changes.